# Validity of href attribute without a value

Tags: html, href

Is `<a href>some text</a>` a valid html code?

This one `<a href="#">some text</a>` is valid.

What about the first one? Is that a typo or it is allowed to skip `=""`?

Comment: Blank links in general are a bad idea. Use a styled `span` if you want to mimic a link but execute a client side function./

Comment: No, that isn't valid, as the `href` attribute needs a value. `<a>some text</a>`, however, is technically valid in HTML5.

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check says it's invalid.

Comment: Downvoter, could you please explain what's wrong with my question. Thank you.

Comment: @FelixKling It does? Validator says this input is VALID: http://pastebin.com/zyDcigBT

Comment: @JoeFrambach Validator `!=` the spec (and it even labels the HTML5 validator as experimental).

Comment: @joe: it's invalid in HTML4. It still generates a warning in HTML5 (as you already noticed yourself). So if I say it's invalid you can assume I tested it in HTML4 ;)

Answer (score 3):

The markup `<a href>some text</a>` is valid (and equivalent to `<a href="">some text</a>`) according to HTML5 CR in HTML serialization, but not otherwise.

General HTML5 rules on HTML serialization (HTML syntax) allow [empty attribute syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0): “Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.” And the empty string is a valid URL, referring to the current document.

In XHTML, `<a href>some text</a>` is invalid and not even well-formed, since well-formedness rules (i.e., general XML syntax rules) require that an attribute specicification is of the form name="value" or name='value', with no shortcuts.

In earlier HTML specs, up to and including HTML 4.01, `<a href>some text</a>` is invalid but on other grounds. By the formal rules, an attribute value may never be omitted from an attribute specification, but the name and the equals sign may be omitted, if the attribute is declared with an enumerated set of values. So `<a href>some text</a>` would be valid if there were an attribute for `a` declared with enumerated values so that one of them is `href` (and there is only one such attribute). But there is no such attribute.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your doctype. More importantly, the rendering depends on your client's browser implementation. Chrome, FF, IE>7, etc, these browsers know what you meant, and can pick up the pieces just fine.

**HTML5**

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

The validator says:

> Valid, but WARNING: Attribute href without an explicit value seen. The attribute may be dropped by IE7.

---

**XHTML1.0 Strict** and **XHTML1.0 Transitional**

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`
and
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

The validator says:

> Invalid: "href" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

---

**HTML 4.01 Strict** and **HTML 4.01 Loose**

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html>`
and
`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html>`

The validator says:

> Invalid: "HREF" is not a member of a group specified for any attribute

Comment: `know what you meant` doesn't mean valid HTML. In HTML5, `href` without a value is always invalid.

Comment: This is correct, but the arguments should refer to specifications (and the Candidate Recommendation) rather than validators. Especially HTML5 validators are experimental and have known bugs, some of which are intentional.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not valid. Use:

```
<span class="pseudo-link">Some text</span>
```

and define styles in CSS for class `pseudo-link` to look like a normal link.
`:hover` selector will be important to change font color and underline the text when mouse is over it.
You can then define action for this pseudo-link with Javascript.

Comment: So what's wrong my dear downvoter? Please explain. We are all here to learn something.

Comment: I think someone is having a bad morning on SO today. Oh well.